# Width of child affected by parent when left is set to 50% (for example)

Tags: html, css

If I try the old absolute centering trick of left:50% and transform:translate(-50%, 0) on a child element that is a table (with 'auto' width), the width is limited to 50% of the parent:

What I want:

```
-----------------------------------------
|                                       |
|                                       |
|                                       |
|     -----------------------------     |
|     |                           |     |
|     |                           |     |
|     |                           |     |
|     -----------------------------     |
|                                       |
|                                       |
|                                       |
-----------------------------------------
```

But what I get is:

```
-----------------------------------------
|                                       |
|                                       |
|                                       |
|          --------------------         |
|          |                  |         |
|          |                  |         |
|          |                  |         |
|          --------------------         |
|                                       |
|                                       |
|                                       |
-----------------------------------------
```

The reason being, when 50% left is applied it's reduced in width to fit the parent:

```
-----------------------------------------
|                                       |
|                                       |
|                                       |
|                   --------------------|
|                   |                  ||
|                   |                  ||
|                   |                  ||
|                   --------------------|
|                                       |
|                                       |
|                                       |
-----------------------------------------
```

Which is then centered using translate.

Any way to overcome this and keep auto width set on the table?

Code here: https://jsfiddle.net/n4f9v5ro/3/

Only seems to be a problem when the child is display:block?

Comment: is there anycode aside the nice pictures ? Just in case you do need help ;)

Comment: Doesn't make any difference?

Comment: Why are you setting display: block; on the table in the first place? Would wrapping the table in a div suit your needs better?

Comment: I did that, but the div is block by nature and results in the same problem: https://jsfiddle.net/n4f9v5ro/3/

Comment: Yes, I've also found that the width of a child is affected by their parents.

Comment: just give the absolute div a width and the table will fit in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can center by using auto margins instead of `left: 50%` and `translateX(-50%)`.

```css
.main {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 30px;
}
.main > div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
table {
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>some long text some long text some long text some long text some long text</td>
        <td>something else</td>
        <td>something else</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="main">
  <div>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>some</td>
        <td>small</td>
        <td>text</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But consider using flexbox.